# Error reading database file from: /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/resources/srs.db

Tags: qgis, mac

I've suddenly started getting the following error using QGIS 2.0.1 on Mac:

```
Error reading database file from:
/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/resources/srs.db
Because of this the projection selector will not work...
```

This results in my map not rending at all and the application frequently crashing. What is causing this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a problem with corrupted file permissions.

To fix, open Searchlight and type in `Disk Utility`. Pick the drive that has QGIS installed on it, click the `First Aid` tab, then click `Repair Disk Permission`. Once this has completed QGIS should start working correctly again.